Pushups for SI joint stability
For strengthening the muscles to help SI joint instability, lower back exercises such as bridges, cat-cow exercises are recommended. Can pushups be employed to strengthen those muscles around SI joints?

The sacroiliac joint is directly stabilised by some muscles for the outer rotation of the hip (the piriformis and some bundles of the glutes) and passively stabilised between the back muscles (latissimus and erector spinae) and the glutes via the lumbar thoracic fascia. Other passive stabilisers are the pelvic floor and transversus abdomini. Neither of these muscles experiences stimuli that are sufficient for significant training effects while doing pushups.
Actually, doing planks and lifting the toes from the ground alternately while keeping the pelvis in level is a rather good exercise for SI stabilisation because it engages all these muscles more pointedly.

@philipklocking

@rajesh If this answers your question, please activate the tick left of this answer to mark it as accepted. That way, you signal your question has been answered.
